# How to get the Microsoft Store URL from Get-AppXPackage output or AppxManifest.xml?

Tags: modern-ui, windows-store-app, microsoft

To get info about an AppX package I can use `Get-AppXPackage`, e.g. for Windows Calculator

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers *windowscalculator*


Name                   : Microsoft.WindowsCalculator
Publisher              : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture           : X64
ResourceId             :
Version                : 10.1809.2731.0
PackageFullName        : Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1809.2731.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation        : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1809.2731.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework            : False
PackageFamilyName      : Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId            : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
PackageUserInformation : {$SIDA [DOMAIN\$user]: Installed,
                         $SIDB [$localadmin]: Installed,
                         $SIDC [DOMAIN\$otheruser]: Installed}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
NonRemovable           : False
Dependencies           : {Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                         Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1809.2731.0_neutral_split.language-de_8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                         Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1809.2731.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged      : False
SignatureKind          : Store
Status                 : Ok
```

How can I get the Microsoft store URL from that output?
Is the AppxManifest.xml of any use?

E.g. for Windows Calculator the URL is https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9WZDNCRFHVN5

Answer (score 1):

I advise that you use `winget` to obtain the ID of the application.

```ps
PS C:\Users\> winget search "Windows Calculator" --source=msstore
Name               Id           Version Source
------------------------------------------------
Windows Calculator 9WZDNCRFHVN5 Unknown msstore
```

You can copy it and add it to this url: https://apps.microsoft.com/detail. Thus, the Microsoft Store's URL for the app is: https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9WZDNCRFHVN5 as indicated in the comments.

Comment: The final URL is : `https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9WZDNCRFHVN5`.

Comment: This is an alternative to the Microsoft Store search via App or website. I'd like to derive the Store Id from an installed Package name, without online lookup. The Store app does this too somehow. I'd like to access that relation directly. It might also be a registry key or some hash/encoding of an AppX property.

Comment: @cachius winget is a Microsoft tool and one of its sources is Microsoft Store that is why it can retrieve apps' IDs.

Comment: I unterstand that, only it's not what I want. I need to obtain the id string „ 9WZDNCRFHVN5“ from the information on disk.